# React-Native: Convert local image to base64 string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

Convert local image to base64 string in Javascript. I'm test in android device and my image path like:

../../Images/Stickers/Bigottario/14.png

How can I convert images from the project local folder to base64?
I have tried with react-native-fs as given below.

```
        RNFS.readFile(this.state.StateStrickersobject.imagePath, 'base64').then(image => {
            alert("22222222222222222"+image)
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

Example image uploader component may be helpful for you. 
Note: **react-native-image-picker** module is required. translation service is optional

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {
    Item, Label, Thumbnail, Button, Icon, Text
} from 'native-base';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import { translate } from '../../Services/Translation/TranslationService';

selectPhotoTapped = ({ Image, onDataChanged }) => {
    const options = { quality: 1.0, maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500, storageOptions: { skipBackup: true } };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        if (response.didCancel) {         // console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        }
        else if (response.error) {            // console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        }
        else if (response.customButton) {            // console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        }
        else {
            Image = Image ? Image : {};
            Image.uri = response.uri;
            Image.ImageStream = response.data;
            onDataChanged(Image);
        }
    });
}

const ImageUploader = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Item fixedLabel style={{ paddingRight: 10 }} error={props.error}>
                <Label>
                    {props.children}
                </Label>
                <Button block onPress={() => selectPhotoTapped(props)} style={{ backgroundColor: "#8995A6" }}>
                    <Text uppercase={false}>{translate("choose_file")}</Text>
                    <Icon name='camera' />
                </Button>
            </Item>
        </View>
    );
}

export { ImageUploader };
```

Example display method

```
<ImageUploader 
  error={checkError(`${prefix}DocumentImages`)} 
  Image={this.state.image}
  onDataChanged={(image) => console.log(image)} >
  <Label> Select photo</Label>
</ImageUploader>
```